# How do devs maintain old projects?

Tags: node.js, npm

A year ago I've made a project for a course: https://github.com/GeorgeFlorian/Finished_link_project
Now, I am trying to make it work on my machine, but I have no luck.

I've got `npm 7.13.0` and `node 16.1.0`.
I've ran `npm update` in order to update all the depencies.

#### Steps

1. I've cloned the repo into a PC than runs Linux Mint 20.1
2. I've ran `npm install`
3. `npm update`

`npm run build` and `npm run serve` return the same error:

```
georgeflorian@georgeflorian-desktop:~/New Volume/VSCode Projects/Finished_link_project$ npm run build

> proiect-link@0.1.0 build
> vue-cli-service build


⠧  Building for production...

 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     2:55:41 PM

Syntax Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'parseComponent' of undefined


You may use special comments to disable some warnings.
Use // eslint-disable-next-line to ignore the next line.
Use /* eslint-disable */ to ignore all warnings in a file.
 ERROR  Build failed with errors.
```

I have no idea how to trace the error: `Syntax Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'parseComponent' of undefined`.

Also, the NodeJS server won't start:

```
georgeflorian@georgeflorian-desktop:~/New Volume/VSCode Projects/Finished_link_project/server$ node app.js 
node:internal/fs/utils:343
    throw err;
    ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/georgeflorian/New Volume/VSCode Projects/Finished_link_project/dist/favicon.ico'
    at Object.statSync (node:fs:1527:3)
    at resolveSync (/home/georgeflorian/New Volume/VSCode Projects/Finished_link_project/node_modules/serve-favicon/index.js:187:17)
    at favicon (/home/georgeflorian/New Volume/VSCode Projects/Finished_link_project/node_modules/serve-favicon/index.js:61:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/georgeflorian/New Volume/VSCode Projects/Finished_link_project/server/app.js:46:9)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1109:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1138:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:989:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:829:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  errno: -2,
  syscall: 'stat',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: '/home/georgeflorian/New Volume/VSCode Projects/Finished_link_project/dist/favicon.ico'
}
```

I believe that many dependencies are deprecated, but this begs two questions:

1. If it worked back then and it hasn't been touched since, why doesn't it work now ?
2. How can I fix all the deprecated dependencies if `npm update` did not fix them ?

Ultimately, I would like to learn how to approach this kind of situation. Thank you.

Comment: "*If it worked back then and it hasn't been touched since, why doesn't it work now ?*" the *project* hasn't been touched but the environment where you run the project most likely has been. Without a good way of tracking what changed on the machine, you've limited options. To make sure it's stable you can do at least one of the following 1. Document *very well* what's needed to run the project from scratch. 2. Make some sort of bootstrap step. A script or at least a list of commands to copy/paste until it works. 3. Deploy in Docker so you know what the environment is.

Comment: Do I have any chance of making it work right now without modifying that much ? Or should I just go ahead and remove `node_modules`, start installing dependencies one by one, replace the deprecated ones and update the code accordingly ? And then document the versions of vue, vue-cli, nodejs, npm, OS ?

Comment: "*Do I have any chance of making it work right now without modifying that much ?*" ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ it's your project. I don't even know the code or dependencies it has. It will take me way longer to just get my head around the project because I've never seen it before.

Comment: I see a lot of deprecated stuff inside the code. Even the ESLinter got deprecated. I think I will just salvage what I can and start anew. I was still curious about how do old projects get maintained since a lot of dependencies get updates or get deprecated or the dependency's dependency changes in some way.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation for maintaining your old Node projects, and dependency hell, is to **use Docker to freeze your dependencies** in place.

For example, something like the below very simple Docker file will ensure that your environment is always the same.

```
FROM node:12.16.1

RUN npm install -g ember-cli@3.9.0

EXPOSE 4200
```

You can then save the Docker image, so that even if the dependencies disappear, you'll always have an image with the dependencies you require.

Of course, you'll want to follow package-lock.json best practices as well. (Here is a good guide regarding package-lock.json: https://medium.com/pavesoft/package-lock-json-the-complete-guide-2ae40175ebdd